# What is the Xubuntu sound recorder application?

Tags: audio, xubuntu, audio-recording

What sound recorder is provided by Xubuntu 11.10 or is lightweight and would be a good candidate for the XFCE desktop?

Comment: If you are talking about a package that comes with the standard installation of Xubuntu, we need to know which version of Xubuntu you are using.

Comment: Have you tried going to the Software Centre and typing "sound recorder" in there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Xubuntu 11.10 does not come prepackaged with a sound recording utility. If you are looking for something simple, I recommend the **Sound Recorder** utility (as [Mokubai](https://superuser.com/users/19943/mokubai) suggested), which is installed with the `gnome-media` package.

[image]